# Unable to set custom position on window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mdi

I'm using the http://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/ library to handle MDI in my WPF application.

I've got a `Canvas` which contains a child container, and all the small windows are to be placed in here.  I want the windows to be opened at position x=500, y=500. However with my current code the windows are always opened at the top left corner of the canvas.

Below I've pasted my XAML and the code which opens a new window in the canvas.

```
<Canvas Name="cnvsMain" Background="LightGray" AllowDrop="True" Drop="cnvsMain_Drop">
     <mdi:MdiContainer Name="mainContainer" Background="LightGray">
     </mdi:MdiContainer>
</Canvas>


            TableWindow tableWindow = new TableWindow(tableName);
            listTableWindows.Add(tableWindow);

            mainContainer.Children.Add(new MdiChild()
            {
                MaximizeBox = false,
                MinimizeBox = false,
                Resizable = true,
                ShowIcon = false,
                Title = "X",
                Position = new Point(500,500),
                Content = tableWindow.Content as UIElement //Opens new instance of my window class
            });
```

Any ideas? I've also tried setting the position from my window class too, to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just spitballing here since I haven't worked with that particular library, but instead of

```
mainContainer.Children.Add(new MdiChild()
{
    MaximizeBox = false,
    MinimizeBox = false,
    Resizable = true,
    ShowIcon = false,
    Title = "X",
    Position = new Point(500,500),
    Content = tableWindow.Content as UIElement //Opens new instance of my window class
});
```

have you tried

```
var child = new MdiChild
{
    MaximizeBox = false,
    MinimizeBox = false,
    Resizable = true,
    ShowIcon = false,
    Title = "X",
    Position = new Point(0, 0),
    Content = tableWindow.Content as UIElement //Opens new instance of my window class
};

mainContainer.Children.Add(child);
child.Position = new Point(500, 500);
//      or
//child.Margin = new Thickness(500, 500, 0, 0);
```

Comment: It actually seems to have worked, however for some reason the window does not appear the first time - only when the code is run twice in a row do the windows appear.

Comment: @DotNET that's odd, maybe try setting `Position = new Point(0, 0)` in the initializer and re-setting it after adding it to the `Children` collection?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, could you kindly elaborate?

Comment: @DotNET see the edit, if the issue is that the Position property needs to get set twice, we'll just set it twice

Comment: I just tried it and it doesn't seem to work either. It's rather odd, as it works perfectly after one window has been added. And infact after another window is added, the first one then gets displayed

Comment: That's really weird, not quite sure what to suggest

Comment: I'll open another question just for this issue - thanks for the help :)